# Generic casting in Typescript

Tags: generics, casting, typescript

I'm trying to create a simple generic find function in TypeScript, along the lines of:

```
export function findFirst<T, U>(
        array: T[], 
        predicate: (item: T) => boolean, 
        selector?: (item: T) => U): U {
     ...
}
```

So, my parameters are:
- the array to filter through
- a predicate to test each element
- a selector to get the return value

What I want to do is provide a default selector, i.e. if no selector is provided, just return the whole value, i.e. something like:

```
if (typeof selector === "undefined")
    selector = (x) => x;
```

However this, (or even `(x) => <U>x`) breaks the generic definition of the function. How can I achieve a default selector without removing the generic parameters?

---

If I use code like:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
var even = findFirst(arr, x => x % 2 === 0);
```

i.e. return the first even number, it infers the type of y as `{}` i.e. `object` instead of number. 
It seems that, as U can only be inferred from the `selector` parameter, which is undefined in this case, U defaults to `object`.
I know I ask a bit too much of the type inference, but is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the complete code:

```
export function findFirst<T, U>(
        array: T[], 
        predicate: (item: T) => boolean, 
        selector: (item: T) => U = (x:T)=> <U><any>x): U {
     return array.filter(predicate).map(selector)[0];
}
```

Reason for `<U><any>` : Type `T` can be asserted to type `U` *only* if T is a subtype of U OR U is a subtype of T. Since that is not determinable you need to convert to `<any>` *before* you can assert to `<U>`

Comment: Yes, `T` is not castable to `U`, but `T` is castable to `any` which is then castable to `U`. Thx,

Answer (score 2):

Since a `U` isn't necessarily a `T`, you'd need to change the type assertion to be less specific by using `any`:

```
selector = x => <any>x;
```

Comment: Tnx, at least the compiler is happy now.

Answer (score 1):

You can just move the default value to the parameter declaration.

```
function findFirst<T, U>(
    array: T[], 
    predicate: (item: T) => boolean, 
    selector: (item: T) => U = (x => x)): U {
       // ....
}
```