# TypeScript: coerce generics T and U

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm writing a library with this API:

```
export var reduce = <T, U>(
  tArray: T[],
  tReducer: (current: U, tItem: T, index: number, tArray: T[]) => U,
  options: IChunkifyOptions = DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
  memo?: U
): Promise<U>
```

The implementation, like the standard JavaScript [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) uses the first item of `tArray` as `memo` if no `memo` was provided.

```
if (memo === undefined) {
  memo = tArray[0]; // Type 'T' is not assignable to Type 'U'
}
```

Casting (`<U>`) gives, reasonably, `Neither Type 'T' nor Type 'U' is assignable to the other.`

What would be a reasonable way to define the API?

Comment: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28310171/2419669). Cast to `<any>` first!

Comment: Use `<any>` casting with caution. Overriding the type safety of TypeScript can lead to many unforeseen issues. I only allow this in test mocks and stubs with my team, and for good reason. Please take a second to consider the below answer before resorting to an `<any>` cast.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `T` is not assignable to `U` as the error explains. Here's the rundown...

In your example if `memo` is not defined then assign `memo` the first item in `tArray`

```
if (memo === undefined) {
  memo = tArray[0]; 
}
```

You have declared that `memo` is `U` and you are attempting to assign it the value of a `T`

`T !== U` and therefor you get the error.

Now it may be tempting to simply cast them using `memo = <U><any>tArray[0]` but ask yourself "Why is this necessary?"

What is your intention for `memo` to hold? What happens when someone uses different objects?

```
reduce<Car, Watermelon>(...)
```

I suspect that you have a different intention here. Could it be that `memo` should really be of type `T | U`? does `T extend U`?

Going down the `<U><any>` path could lead to many many unexpected runtime errors and hard to find bugs as your API increases. I think that you need to take a second look at the behavior you want before resorting taking the easy way out with `<U><any>`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried `extends` before, but you can't  constrain a type based on another type in the same "bracket". I'll think more about this, but when I play with the exported API, the compiler seems to behave as expected, with or without a provided `memo`.

I definitely don't think `T` or `U` should constrain each other, though.

Comment: Then I would recommend `memo: T | U` since that's essentially what you are doing with the `<U><any>` anyways